# Add thumbnails to ResponsiveSlide.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a custom thumbnail gallery using ResponsiveSlide.js but can't seem to figure out how I can trigger individual slides. I'm not sure if I can call it with a CSS change or if I need to use JS. I'm also pretty new to jQuery too so that doesn't help.

What I have so far is a working slideshow, and thumbnails link but I can't trigger the slide change when I click on them.

```
<a onClick="$('#slider1_s2').addClass(activeClass)" href="#">thumb image</a>
```

slider1_s2 is the ID tag of the slide I am trying to call in this instance, but it could be any slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the plugin do the work for you. If you want a group of thumbnails to link to the associated images in the slideshow, then you need to make it yourself.

```
$("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
    manualControls: '#unique-pager'
});
```

There you're linking the images in the slideshow to the images in the `#unique-pager` you'll be creating.

This is modified straight from Viljamis's demo code

```
<!-- slideshow -->
<ul class="slides" id="slider">
  <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>

<!-- Pager -->
<ul id="unique-pager"> <!--this id gets inserted in manualControls -->
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/1_thumb.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/2_thumb.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/3_thumb.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
```